# Rails3, Unknown key(s): client_id, on belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've been searching for a while now, but google isn't really helping me.
The ArgumentError `Unknown key(s): client_id` appears in the ProjectsController:

```
# projects_controller.rb

class Management::ProjectsController < Management::ManagementController
  def index
    @projects = Project.find( :client_id => current_user.client )
  end
end
```

This is the project model:

```
# project.rb

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

This is the client model:

```
# client.rb

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

And finally, the migration:

```
# 20110404155917_create_projects.rb

class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :date
      t.text :description
      t.integer :client_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :projects
  end
end
```

Should be possible, right?

Can't see what I'm missing here..

Anyone got a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
@projects = Project.where( :client_id => current_user.client.id)
```

or

```
@projects = Project.find_by_client_id(current_user.client.id)
```

Comment: +1 I was just typing exact the same thing :) You can also use `@projects = Project.where(:client => current_user.client)`

Comment: Or `@projects = Project.find(:first,:conditions=>{ :client_id => current_user.client.id})`

Comment: Indeed, that's it! When thinking of it, I made this mistake before.. How could I forget? Well, it works now, and writing it down! Thanks! ------- EDIT: I still find it kind of strange that it's giving the error "Unknown key(s)", because it makes you believe it works but can't find the key(s) in the table..

Answer (score 0):

or you could do

```
@projects = current_user.client.projects
```

Little bit cleaner perhaps?

Comment: That's cleaner indeed, but I changed the code to this for now: `@projects = params[:client_id] ? Project.where( :client_id => params[:client_id] ) : Project.all` So I can't use it for this, but will keep it in mind.. Thanks!